# Php - How to search for a page on web

Tags: php, search

I want to make a page that search a determined web page and return it, Google scraping it's illegal so I want to know if there is anything else

Comment: You can start here http://subinsb.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-crawler-in-php

Comment: What do you mean `determined web page`? The user gives a website and a term and wants to know if there is a match? If that you could `curl` to the URL, get the content, and scan it. That may/may not be against the terms of the website. It has no relation to `Google` though.